# Ignore all files in subfolders but specifc files

Tags: git, gitignore

I am working in a project with the following structure

```
Data/
   folder1/
      file1
      file2
      important.txt
   folder2/
      file3
      file4
      important.txt
   folder3/
      file5
      file6
      important.txt
README.md
.gitignore
several other files and folders
```

I want to keep track of everything except for the **files** inside each **folder** in **Data**. I want to keep track of **important.txt** also.
What I can't do is to ignore everything inside Data but the important files. I looked at some solutions that basically start with ignoring everything and later negating the specific files they want to track, but I don't want to do that because the project contains many files and negating one by one those is a quite annoying.

What my gitignore looks like now

```
#Ignore Data (and its contents)
Data
#but not subfolders
!Data/
#ignore everything inside subsubfolders
Data/*/*
#but not the important files
!Data/**/important.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention whether you can have, e.g.:

```
Data/long/path/to/folder/trash
Data/long/path/to/folder/important.txt
```

and if so whether you need to keep `important.txt` as a committed file, but I'll assume that this occurs.  Here's how *I* would do it:

- At the top level, have no `.gitignore`;
- in `Data` have a `.gitignore` that reads:

  ```
  *
  !.gitignore
  !important.txt
  !*/
  ```

This tells Git that once it descends into `Data/` to do a recursive add or check for untracked files, it should:

- ignore everything; but
- *don't* ignore (so do check for and/or en-masse add) `.gitignore` itself;
- *don't* ignore `important.txt` either; and
- *do* descend, recursively, into any sub-directory.

Since none of these rules are *anchored* these same four rules apply, in that order, to every sub-directory.

Comment: Got interrupted, lost count. Fixed.